# Azure Service Bus Relay Security

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am developing a program which uses the Azure Service Bus Relay to transfer information from a server to a client.

My question is, how is this information secured? Is the data I am requesting encrypted with SSL or is the data sent plaintext? I am using a `webHttpRelayBinding`, opening a `WebServiceHost` via `AddServiceEndpoint`. All in C#. I then fetch data from this service via `GET` requests.

If plaintext, how can I easily encrypt the requested data?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the listener end (on premise service registering and connecting to ServiceBus), this is secured by default. All communications from and to ServiceBus is performed over SSL. To secure the data between the sender (consumer of the service) and ServiceBus, you will need to setup the ServiceBus endpoint to use https so that the data between sender and ServiceBus is over SSL as well. In other words, register the ServiceBus endpoint with URL scheme set to https.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: This is what I need to do Sachin - but how.